# Remove a noscript tag inside the head tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to remove a `<noscript>` tag with JavaScript. But every attempt so far has failed.

I tried these:

```
// The noscript tag has a id. I'm accessing it over this id
var noscript = window.document.getElementById("noscript_with_id");

noscript.parentNode.removeChild(noscript); // noscript.parentNode is null
noscript.outerHTML = "";                   // doesn't do anything
noscript.innerHTML = "";                   // doesn't do anything
```

I must not use jQuery. Just plain JavaScript.

Since I am accessing the element over an specific ID and using it's content a working solution might be changing the ID or emptying the content. I need to remove it because the code working with the element might be executed several times.

The noscript tag is located inside the `<head>` tag. I use this to asynchronously load some stylsheets.

I set up a page with the problem. https://blitz.icon-craft.net/layout_test/
Check the console and https://blitz.icon-craft.net/includes/js/loadCSS.js

*(I want to note that this site in fact uses jQuery. But I plan on using the script on sites that do not use it. It wouldn't make any sense including jQuery just for this tiny script.)*

Comment: When are you running the Javascript code? Has the `noscript` element been parsed at that time?

Comment: I don't think `<noscript>` is part of the DOM and the content only would be if JS was disabled.

Comment: Why would you want to remove a `noscript` element with JS? The very fact that you're running JS means that `noscript` has no effect, it might not even get inserted into the DOM since it's useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942856/how-to-remove-noscript-tag-wrapper-with-jquery

Comment: @Guffa Yes it has been parsed. Otherwise I would not be able to access its content.

Comment: @DanielImms There is some code which is modified and injected into the DOM. I placed it inside a `<noscript>` tag so that the application still works.

Comment: @BrainStone could you provide us with a Fiddle of the element which you're get with `getElementById`?

Comment: @Leeish all answers use jQuery. Which is not an option for me.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of successfully removing a `<noscript>` using native javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/nc1cokqw/

Comment: @DuncanThacker, your fiddle doesn't do anything(?)  Here's a fiddle that shows that `noscript.parentNode.removeChild(noscript)` works:  http://jsfiddle.net/r2srnx34/

Comment: Ok. After hours of debugging I found the source of my problem. When I change the content of the `<head>` tag a reference to the noscript tag became invalid. Once I made sure I had a fresh instance of the object everything worked. Should I make a solution/answer or simply update my question?

Comment: @BrainStone - since you've solved the problem yourself, it is perfectly normal and reasonable to answer the question and award the correct solution to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Removing the element works just as described here several times and just as I was doing it.

The problem was that I changed the content of the parent (in this case the `<head>` tag) and therefore the object which i saved in a variable became invalid.

Here is the not working code:

```
var noscript = window.document.getElementById("some_id");
var head = window.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

head.innerHTML += noscript.innerHTML;    // After that noscript is no longer valid
head.removeChild(noscript);              // Won't work
```

The following will work:

```
var noscript = window.document.getElementById("some_id");
var head = window.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

var content = noscript.innerHTML;
head.removeChild(noscript);
head.innerHTML += content;
```

Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `<head>` tag is the parent.

```
var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
for(var i in noscript) {
    parent.removeChild(noscript[i]);
}
```

I tested this on SO site and it worked. The `noscript` tag lives inside the `body` tag so the code is obviously different to select the `body` tag.

It will fail if the `noscript` tags have different parents. Only the ones that are scoped to the parent you select will remove.

Comment: I am doing it like this but it is not working. It appears the noscript element is not in the DOM whe I try to remove it but it is when I read its content...

Comment: If you wrap that in `document.addEventListener('ready', function() { // that script }, false);`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to ensure that the tag exists when the javascript is called. I do this by waiting until all elements, images and scripts have been loaded.

Next, you don't need to use an id - you can grab it with any number of methods. The NodeList returned by getElementsByTagName is *live* and as such, changes size to reflect operations on the collection of elements it represents - this is why there's only one call needed to `getElementsByTagName`.

I forget the specifics, but I read about it the other day. either querySelector/querySelectorAll may have been the odd one out - returning an array that doesn't change as the document does. Dunno, probably mostly irrelevant here anyway.

Here's a working sample:

**EDIT:** Code altered. 
(1) to fire on a button press, so you can see the effect in the DOM viewer of your browser's JS tools.
(2) moved the noscript tag to the head

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <noscript>You appear to have javascript disabled</noscript>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
    function onDocLoaded(evt)
    {
    //  nukeNoscripts();
    }

    function nukeNoscripts()
    {
        var tgtTags = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');
        alert("Num of noscript tags: " + tgtTags.length);
        var tgt = tgtTags[0];
        tgt.parentNode.removeChild(tgt);
        alert("Num of noscript tags: " + tgtTags.length);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='nukeNoscripts()'>NUKE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a noscript tag with JavaScript

```
var noscr = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript').length;
    for(var yh = 0;yh<noscr;yh++) {document.getElementsByTagName('noscript')[0].remove();}
```

Comment: For a useful answer explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me and I had the 'noscript' tag in body. Below code worked eventually:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('noscript');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a simple way to do it

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[unwrap]").forEach(function(a){a=a.textContent;a=document.createRange().createContextualFragment(a);document.body.appendChild(a)});
```

```html
 <noscript unwrap>
  <link href="some_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
 </noscript>
```